# Authentication Issue with Spark Snowflake Connector using OAuth

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to setup the Spark Snowflake Connector and hit this error:
`"IllegalArgumentException: A snowflake passsword or private key path must be provided with 'sfpassword or pem_private_key' parameter, e.g. 'password'"`

I am not trying to authenticate with a password but rather an OAuth token. Using PySpark and set the following options:

```
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"
SNOWFLAKE_OPTIONS = {
    'sfURL': os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_URL", sf_url),
    'sfUser': os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_USER", user_id),
    'sfAuthenticator': os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_AUTH_METHOD", "oauth"),
    'sfToken': os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_TOKEN", oauth_token),
    'sfDatabase': os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE", sf_db),
    'sfSchema': os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA", sf_schema),
    'sfWarehouse': os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE", sf_warehouse),
    'sfRole':  os.environ.get("SNOWFLAKE_ROLE", sf_role)
    }
```

Versions:

- Spark: spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2
- Snowflake Connector: spark-snowflake_2.12-2.8.2-spark_3.0.jar
- Snowflake JDBC: snowflake-jdbc-3.12.14.jar

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error as you while using OAuth with the Spark Snowflake Connector. I was doing it in Databricks, however.

The solution that fixed it for me was updating the Spark version. I was using an out of date and unsupported version of Spark (2.4.5), and I updated it to version 3.1.1.